# effort_controller for JointGroupVelocityController

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not able to find this type of controller `effort_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController`. Does ROS have this type of controller? As far as I know there is a group of position controller for effort interface. Could anyone please confirm this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401200/effort_controller-for-jointgroupvelocitycontroller/) by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2022-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I check [GitHub](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/tree/melodic-devel/effort_controllers/src), they don't seem to have `JointGroupVelocityController`. They do have `JointGroupEffortController` and `JointGroupPositionController`.

[velocity_controllers](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/tree/melodic-devel/velocity_controllers/src) does seem to have it. So you might want to try `velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController`.

Also, make sure you've got `ros_controllers` also installed, not just `ros_control`.

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2022-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2022-05-24**:
I've checked that link as well. I didn't find it.